# Bootstrap Popover isn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

My bootstrap popover is not showing up.

Here is my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div align='left' id='person'>Person</div>

<div id="popoverEditPerson" class="hide">
    <form>
        <h4>Enter Name:</h4>
        <input id='nameInput' type='text' placeholder='Name'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#person').popover({
        html: true,
        title: 'Edit Person<a class="close" href="#");">&times;</a>',
        content: $('#popoverEditPerson').html(),
        placement: 'auto'
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: use double quotes for html attributes ```<div align="left" id="person">Person</div>```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is set the class='hide' not on the popoverEditPerson div itself but around it like so:

```
<div class="hide">
  <div id="popoverEditPerson">
      <form>
          <h4>Enter Name:</h4>
          <input id='nameInput' type='text' placeholder='Name'/>
      </form>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ue1kss3v/1/

If I click on the person, it works as expected